# Regex-ing Static HTML Table into VB.net

Tags: regex, vb.net

I want to import all of a table on a website so I can access the information. 
The table looks like this

http://jsfiddle.net/Crystalwolf/cdX7d/

The information I will be regex-ing is a page with just tables and nothing else.
I am hoping to get the information I need through common tag beginnings and ends.
The results would be fine to go into a separate listbox for me to then handle the data.

All I need to do is import it all into a listbox which I partially did.

```
    Dim moose As String
    Dim regex As New RegularExpressions.Regex("<\s*tr[^>]*>(.*?)<\s*/\s*tr>")
    Dim results As New StringBuilder
    For Each m As RegularExpressions.Match In regex.Matches(Form2.WebBrowser1.DocumentText)
        results.Append(m.Value)
        moose = results.ToString
        ListBox1.Items.Add(moose)
    Next
```

However Regex is not my strong point and all this does is print the same line in my listbox multiple times. As well as include excess data that I do not need.

I've tried using Regex helpers and other stuff but I haven't been able to find a way for me to grab the information I need.

Which is
30/231-16 (231-16)
RELEASE BEARING 
£14.82

Only idea I have is to import all the table data into listboxes and then regex using the common parts of the table. 
By that I mean grabbing the word RELEASE BEARING inbetween the `&nbsp;` and the `<br>`

```
&nbsp;&nbsp;RELEASE BEARING <br>
```

This is why I think using regular between html tags Regex will most likely not work.
It would also need to work so even when it has a different name/productnumber/price it is still able to grab the information.
If I could be pointed in the correct direction I'd appreciate it.

(Also I know it can be bad to use Regex to sort through HTML however I'm running out of options that I know about.)

Comment: are you seeking a regex to grame the string `30/231-16 (231-16) RELEASE BEARING 14.82` from the html page? (if yes, better edit your qeustion's title)

Comment: I didn't want to create two separate questions for this.
I do want to regex it I just thought that'd it'd be possile/better to use some kind of importing if possible.

Comment: better doing so - as your question is not very clear... submitting two questions with proper tag will attract more members to help you

Comment: I've further elaborated my question as well as editing the title. Would you say that I have sufficient information now?

Comment: Please add some examples... what is the input and what is the expected output?

Comment: My input is a html document with only tables and the expected output I'm after is a listbox with the data I need and stated. I have mentioned so in my question now.

Comment: Write real examples not just definition... e.g., "here is an HTML..." here is the list box examples.... (i would take our discussion to a chat room, but you don't have any rep for that (yet))